# Eclipse New Java Class Wizard in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to create Java class in VS Code similar to [Eclipse New Java Class Wizard](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_create_java_class.htm)?

I would like VS Code to add package and class declarations automatically like Eclipse does.

Couldn't find relevant info in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) and relevant functionality in plugins.

Comment: As far as I know, in VS Code there are no such dialogs similar to Eclipse. Instead, you have to create a file with the extension `.java` and then use the `class` template (see e.g. [here](https://dzone.com/articles/visual-studio-code-for-java-the-ultimate-guide-201)). See also [documentation, section _Getting started_](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java#_getting-started): in the image, there is a _Create a Class_ section where it says _"Create a File"_, not _"Use the ... dialog/wizard"_.

Comment: It's a good suggestion,you could report it on the [vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) github.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue, coming from Eclipse/IDEA background, you can find it difficult to not have a feature in your java IDE to create a new classes, packages etc.

You can use the below VSCode extension : https://github.com/jiangdequan/vscode-java-saber

It is a very handy extension.It provides support/wizard for:

- New: Java files(annotation/class/interface/enum/package/JSP/HTML)
- Generate Getters and Setters
- Copy Qualified Name
- Sort Project By Name
- Run Maven Goals
- Generate Docs

You can try this extension.Search for vscode-java-saber in the extension search and install it.